# How do you implement LintFix to add missing annotation to class definition in Android

Tags: android, lint

I am investigation custom Lint Rules development in my current Android Application.

My detector finds all Activities in my project that are not annotated with a specific annotation.

I would like to create a LintFix that adds the missing annotation as follows:-

Activity in Error

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
}
```

Activity fixed

```
@MyMissingAnnotation
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
}
```

The code I have developed is :-

```
        val fix = LintFix.create()
            .replace()
            .text("")
            .with("@MyMissingAnnotation")
            .build()
```

however this results in the following corrupt code

```
class @MyMissingAnnotationMyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
}
```

as my report resembles this

```
 context.report(
         ISSUE, node,
         context.getNameLocation(node),
         "Activities require the @MyMissingAnnotation annotation.",
          fix
  )
```

How can I add the required annotation at the correct location in my class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `shortenNames()`, `beginning()` and `reformat(true)` to make your fix more reasonable

```
val fix = LintFix.create()
                .replace()
                .text("")
                .with("@com.foo.bar2.MyMissingAnnotation")
                .beginning()
                .shortenNames()
                .reformat(true)
                .range(context.getLocation(node as UElement))
                .build()
```